# JFilechooser exit on close

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jfilechooser

In my java application, there is a browse button. When browse button is clicked, popup a file chooser to select a file. When I close the file chooser by clicking cross mark at the top right corner without selecting a file, it gives an Exception saying "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException". How shall I prevent this error?

```
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        //chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        //chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);

        path=chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
```

Comment: I expect you are using something from the file chooser without checking that it is not null.

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            
            chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
            //chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
            //chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
            
            path=chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you exit the `JFileChooser` without selecting a file, `chooser.getSelectedFile()` will return `null`.

Therefore, on your line `path=chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();` you are getting a `NullPointerException` when you try to call `getPath()` on the `null` selected file, since you exited.

You will need to do some error handling, such as this:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);

File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
if (selectedFile == null) {
    System.out.println("No file selected!");
    path = "";
}
else {
    path = selectedFile.getPath();
}
```

In situations like this, I'd recommend reading through the Javadoc of the method you're retrieving resources from. Quite often under the "returns" section it will state if the returned object can be `null`, or even if it is guarenteed not to be `null`.

It helps me a lot when deciding when and when not to add things like `null` checking.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to go with JFileChooser is using chooser.showOpenDialog(this), which returns a value that indicates what the user clicked.

Instead of

```
chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
```

you can write

```
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
   path=chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
   // whatever other code that only has sense if the user clicked "Ok".
}
```

And now you understood it, the usual faster way:

```
if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { //whatever }
```

You can take a look at the other few values chooser.showOpenDialog() can return, but this is usually enough.